# Логин в react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookie, axios

Например у меня есть метод:

```
static getToken(params) {
    const cookies = new Cookies()
    return axios.post(backendDomen + '/api/oauth/token', {
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: secret,
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: params.email,
        password: params.password,
        scope: '*'
    })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.data.access_token) {
                cookies.set('token', result.data.access_token, { path: '/' })
                window.location.replace('/brokers/customers/list')
            }
        }).catch(function (reason) {
            return reason.response
        })
}
```

Но в других компонентах запросы начинают отправлятся раньше чем токен сохранился в куку, если вывести в консоль то сначала я вижу null, а потом уже токен, хоть он и находится в `then`. Как заставить подождать появление токена в куке?
Или, возможно, есть лучшие способ сохранить токен чем куки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('token', result.data.access_token)
```

Comment: Насколько это безопасно по сравнению с куками? Есть мнение что из localStorage легче украсть токен

Comment: У `localStorage` есть несколько преимуществ например когда куки использовать нельзя (например мобильное приложение), время хранения не ограничено (сохраняет refresh_token) и пр. По безопастности особых отличий нет, куки крадутся через CSRF, а localStorage через XSS. Тут нужно заботиться о ваших токенах.

Comment: так лучше, то ответ с ошибками. не localStorage.set  а localStorage.setItem

Comment: @Jonny Manowar, спасибо. Поправил